# Read html line by line in VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a script that will pull the html down and put it into a text or HTML file. I can then parse the text file line by line, but I'd rather either parse the website itself or parse the textstream as I get it. Is this possible using VBS (my scripting languages are limited)?

Code:

```
dim URL
url = "www.something.com"
set wshshell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
set http = createObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
on error resume next
http.open "GET", URL, FALSE
http.send
if err.number = 0 then 
    outputFile.writeline http.responsetext
else
    wscript.echo "error " & err.number & ": " & err.description
end if
set wshshell = nothing
set http = nothing
```

patchStatusFile.close

It works fine if I write to an external HTML file. I was wondering if I HAD to write to a file or can I parse the stream first? ie:

```
strToLookAt = http.responsetext

do until strToLookAt.atEndOfStream 
    strLine = strToLookAt.readLine 
    if strLine = "the thing I'm looking for" 
        ...do stuff... 
    end if 
loop
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague. What exactly are you going for? What is the result of your script, and what would you like it to be?

Comment: What I am doing is pulling down SCCM reports via vbscript. The default name for the URL is something like, "\\server\report\random_charactersMachineName=""..." so I fill in the machine name from an external list. Once I open this website, I'd like to parse it for specific lines of HTML code, but so far the only way to do that is to acutally create an HTML file then parse that. I'd like to parse the HTML before I write it to file. Is that more clear?

Comment: That is more clear, but where you are experiencing the problem is not. What have you tried so far? What is not working?

Comment: I put my comment in the question so it would be formatted better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did no one answer such a simple question?

here is an example of what I do.

```
dim up_http : up_http = "http://www.metrolyrics.com/Cornography-lyrics-Brad-Paisley.html"
dim xmlhttp : set xmlhttp = createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlhttp.open "get", up_http, True
xmlhttp.send
LyricsURL = xmlhttp.responseText
'At this point we have the html from the web page in memory variable LyricsURL
```

No need to write to any file. 
You can just process the memory variable line for line.

In this case (script not shown) I have it in a function (get_html). I then process each line of the result of the function looking for a particular strings that mark the beginning and end of the Lyrics. Then I save that result into a variable then I replace and delete characters in this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Never got an answer. What I decided to do was:

1) Create a temp file where I store the text info.
2) Parse temp file.
3) Delete Temp file.

Not best idea, but in all honesty, this isn't the best script anyway. Just realized there was an "export" button on the SCCM report. I am going to see about utilizing that in a script.

Comment: For full code, I posted it here: http://jayscoding.com/2013/02/26/sccm-what-is-my-patch-status/